# Find First Insance of NOT a value

Tags: excel, vba

In a typical find function to find a cell containing the test "DID", the code would look something like

```
Set cell = Selection.Find(What:="DID", After:=ActiveCell, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

However, what if I am trying to find the first instance of anything other than "DID"? I tried out following but does not seem to work.

```
Set cell = Selection.Find(What <> "DID", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Find` and `.FindNext` together. Is this what you want?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range

    Set aCell = Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell

        If aCell.Value <> "DID" Then
            MsgBox aCell.Address
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Do
            Set aCell = Cells.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                If aCell.Value <> "DID" Then
                    MsgBox aCell.Address
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Firstly, thanks for responding.
I understand there is an alternative way to do this by looping and finding the next value that is not "DID". But my question was if i wanted to change the code for finding the first "DID" ie Selection.Find(What:="DID") to finding the first non "DID", is it possible to do so by simply modifying Selection.Find(What:="DID")? As I said earlier, Selection.Find(What<>"DID") does not seem to work.

Comment: I doubt you can do it by saying "<>DID" and hence you need the loop